# What is the correspondent sub-field of this cyclotomic extension, given by the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory?

Tags: galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

I've been working on some problems regarding polynomials, and I ended up with the following question:

Suppose that $\zeta_{p^n}$ is a root of unity of order $p^n$, and consider the cyclotomic extension $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p^n}]|\mathbb{Q}$. The corresponding Galois group has order $\phi(p^n) = (p-1)p^{n-1}$. Therefore, there must be a subgroup of order $p-1$, that should correspond, by the correspondence given in the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory, to some subfield of $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p^n}]$.

I suspect that this subfield is exactly $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p^n}^p] \cong \mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p^{n-1}}]$, but I don't know any reference of this fact. Is there a reference for this? Or if I am wrong, wich subfield should the group correspond to?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For example, when $p=3$ you want a subgroup of order two. This can only be the subgroup generated by the usual complex conjugation. So in that case the corresponding subfield is
$$\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{3^n})\cap\Bbb{R}=\Bbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/3^n).$$ When $p>3$ it is not so easy (where's Will Jagy?).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I just saw this comment now. Thanks a lot for your help! I'll keep trying to understand this extension for the case $p>3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p\ne2$, the Galois group $G$ of the cyclotomic extension is cyclic.  It's $\Bbb Z_{p^n}^×$.  There's one cyclic subgroup of order $p-1$, since $(p-1)\mid\varphi(p^n)$.  Call it $N\triangleleft G$.

$N$ corresponds to an extension $K$ of $\Bbb Q$ of degree $[G:N]=p^{n-1}$.

But $[\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^{n-1}}):\Bbb Q]=\varphi (p^{n-1})$, since it's a cyclotomic extension.

Since, $\varphi (p^{n-1})\ne p^{n-1}$, this is a different extension.

The extension you want is $K=\Bbb Q^N$, the fixed field under the action of $N$.

$K$ is not a cyclotomic extension in this case.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much! I just have two questions:
1) You said that the subgroup of order $p-1$ is cyclic. Does it apply even if $p=2$ ?
2) If we had taken a subgroup of order $p^{n-1}$, would it be true that such $N$ would correspond to $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]$? (since $\phi(p)=p-1$)

Comment: Yes, and I suspect yes.

Comment: @Vitor The case $p=2$ is surely anomalous here. The subgroup of order $p-1$ is then trivial (you can still call it cyclic, I guess). But the Galois group $Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})$, $K=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{2^n})$, is not cyclic when $n\ge3$. For much the same reason that the multiplicative residue class group $\Bbb{Z}_{2^n}^*$ isn't cyclic either. It shows on the field side as non-uniqueness of subfields of a fixed degree. For example $K$ has three quadratic subfields $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$, $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ and $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$ corresponding to the three subgroups of index two.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you